# Google Sheet Filter formula based on range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got some data
Basically a list of Items
and another sheet that contains a list of orders
(Some items can appear in multiple orders, which is why I can't use a vlookup for this)

My problem is I want to get the ALl the Order IDs of all items in dynamic list(in my example there's only 3 items, but that can grow.

I'm trying to use the filter formula and have got this so far:

```
=filter('Orders'!AC1:AD,'Orders'!K:K=A4)
```

[image]

which works fine at retrieving all the Order ID's for the item number in cell A4.

But I want the Order ID's for all the Items in column A.

I tried

```
=filter('Orders'!AC1:AD,'Orders'!K:K=A2:A)
```

But that doesn't work. I'm guessing I need to do some kind of array formula maybe.

But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please can you share a sample Sheet showing your source data as well as the type of outcome you need?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18RUXLGCopweonDUKEA83UKMivn39yo0J5HFA1too_AQ/edit?usp=sharing

This is a sample sheet, the Orange highlight in Summary is what I've been able to do (with a single item #)

the green highlight is what I want to happen (list all order numbers)

the red highlight, is what I've tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function

This is a SQL like syntax to manipulate your data.

```
=query({Orders!$A:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",true,unique(Summary!$A4:$A))&"' ",1)
```

or this if you need to sort the result:

```
=query({Orders!$A:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",true,unique(Summary!$A4:$A))&"' order by Col2 ",1)
```

The first argument is the range that you want to query. Which in this case is inserted with the [array notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) `{Orders!$A:$B}`.

The next argument is a string representing an SQL like statment that in this case says "Select column 2 when column 1 matches Item A or Item C or Item D".

The "Item A or Item C or Item D" part is constructed with another formula, [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992). Just grabbing the range to join and the delimiter is set to the OR operator which is `|`.

Comment: Thanks, it was iansedano who added the explanation to my formula.